# Explode text within a column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset as follows:

```
Col1 Col2 ... Text
...  ...  ... Include details about your goal...
...  ...  ... Avoid asking opinion-based questions.
```

I would need to explode Text column in order to build a frequency plot.
I have tried with: `df.Text.explode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.split()
df = df.explode('Text')

     Col1           Text
0  Value1        Include
0  Value1        details
0  Value1          about
0  Value1           your
0  Value1           goal
1  Value2          Avoid
1  Value2         asking
1  Value2  opinion-based
1  Value2     questions.
```